# How to measure currents between 0.1mA and 100mA?

Tags: microcontroller, current-measurement

**Summary of question:**

I need to measure (using a microcontroller, not via a meter) currents between 0.1mA and 100mA, with a reasonable level of accuracy - say, to within 0.2 of a mA. My power supply is single-rail 5V.

I have tried the ADC of such chips as the ATtiny85 and the PIC16F1503. I have tried the INA219 and the LMP8640. I have tried homebrew op-amp solutions.

How can I measure such currents accurately and reliably using a microcontroller?

**More detail:**

The INA219 and LMP8640 gave wildly fluctuating readings. One minute they would be fairly accurate; next minute they'd be wildly erroneous. I don't understand why this should be.

The same happened when I tried to use the ADC of a microcontroller. These things just don't seem to cope well with really small currents (or voltages).

I tried [this board](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32850921179.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4d5aE2Pk):

[image: AD620 Microvolt MV Voltage Amplifier Signal Instrumentation Module Board]

But having adjusted it to produce sensible results for 2.2mA, I found that it was a whole mA out by the time I got to 10mA.

Then I tried [this op-amp circuit](http://lushprojects.com/circuitjs/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0Aa+96+80+240+80+9+15+-15+1000000+0.008934724186414727+0.008935219657483246+100000%0Ar+16+32+16+128+0+10%0Ar+16+32+96+32+0+2200%0Ar+16+128+96+128+0+2200%0Aw+96+32+96+64+0%0Aw+96+96+96+128+0%0Ar+96+128+240+128+0+10000%0Aw+240+80+240+128+0%0Ar+96+32+240+32+0+10000%0Ag+240+32+256+32+0%0A368+240+80+320+80+0+0%0Ag+16+128+16+144+0%0A370+-64+32+16+32+1+0%0Ar+-64+32+-144+32+0+100%0A172+-144+32+-192+32+0+7+0.12+12+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0A):

[image: op-amp circuit]

I didn't get any useful results from it; probably due to the fact that it's not a rail-to-rail op-amp. Even if it were, I doubt it'd be sufficiently close to the rails to give me a useful output across the entire range.

Comment: What sense resistor did you use with the INA219? That's pretty much a complete subsystem and hard to get wrong. What's the frequency spectrum of the current signal look like (is it brief pulses of high current or is it relatively steady, for example)?

Comment: I have prebuilt modules with 0.1Ω sense resistors. The current to be measured will be fairly steady. For example, I might adjust a pot by hand and have a display indicating the current being used. But I honestly cannot get any of these devices to operate reliably.

Comment: Are you averaging over some number of readings? Do you have any calibrated test equipment to verify how far off you are on the AT/PIC side? Are you using interrupts and/or waiting for the ADC conversion completion before measuring?

Comment: How stable and linear is the voltage a) across the resistor, and b) at the op amp output, when measured with a multimeter?

Comment: "it's not a rail-to-rail op-amp" - which op amp is it?

Comment: I tried averaging over ten ADC readings, it didn't seem to help. I don't have "calibrated" test equipment, but my problem wasn't inaccuracy, it was fluctuating values. I disabled interrupts and waited for the ADC to complete (using Arduino or Great Cow Basic).

Comment: For the op-amp in the diagram above, I used a 4558D. I will perform some measurements and get back to you.

Comment: The ADC was using the VCC as a reference; but I did have decoupling capacitors. I don't know if a dedicated reference might have helped.

Comment: put 0.1uF across the sense-resistor. And use a ground plane, not a protoboard.

Comment: measuring 100mA to better than 0.2mA needs only 500 levels, or about 9 bits. You can buy a 16 bit ADC for peanuts.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I will try the capacitor you suggest. Using a ground plane is an easy thing to *say*, but I don't have a factory, so I can only work with what I have. Getting a board fabricated comes *after* getting the damn thing to work, not before.

Comment: @Neil_UK If you had bothered to read the question, you would have seen that I had already tried microcontroller ADCs and dedicated current-sensing chips. Do you have a particular chip in mind, that is more reliable than everything I have tried so far?

Comment: @SodAlmighty He did read your question.  But speaking of not reading things, did you even read Neil_UK's comment?  It seems like you didn't.  You say you already tried a microcontroller's onboard ADC.  And?  What is your point? We know what you've tried, because you told us in your question.  That is why Neil_UK suggested you use a dedicated ADC chip with higher resolution, which is completely different from what you've tried, and a good suggestion.  ADCs in µCs are garbage and usually have a ENOB much lower than their resolution.  A dedicated ADC will almost always be vastly superior.

Comment: @SodAlmighty Also, no one here owes you anything.  Everyone commenting is a stranger who is choosing to donate some of their time to try and help you.  The only appropriate thing to show is gratitude, and whether you find the comment immediately helpful or not is irrelevant to that.  Plus, it is your fault that his comment wasn't helpful to you, not his.  He is clearly suggesting something other than a uC's ADC.  It's understandable you might not know exactly how they're different, but maybe ask for clarification next time instead of giving a snarky response based on your own bad assumption.

Comment: @SodAlmighty So, I don't quite understand something here.  When you were using the various amplifier or that aliexpress board, how were you measuring the output voltage?  Because your phrasing makes it sound like you used this instead of the micro's ADC, but all of those are intended to be used WITH an ADC.  They sit in front of the ADC to condition the analog signal into a signal more suited to your ADC.  Or is that what you were doing, and you just mean you tried hooking it up to the ADC directly?  Sorry, just double checking what you were attempting.

Comment: @metacollin The INA219 is a dedicated ADC chip, and in my question I said I had tried it. Regarding the aliexpress board and the op-amp circuit, I was using a multimeter to measure their outputs. And the outputs were not useful.

Comment: As I understand it, many µCs have 10-bit ADCs, which should be quite suitable for the task. Besides, my issue wasn't lack of precision, but rather one of fluctuating readings. Except in the case of the Aliexpress board, which suffered from non-linearity.